# Problema de ancho en maquetacion responsive

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

Tengo un problema y es que cuando quiero adaptar mi web a distintos tamaños, llega un momento que algunos elementos dejan de ocupar el 100% de la pantalla, los elementos que me marca el inspector de elementos son la etiqueta html y el body, ya intente ponerles width , min-width de todas las formas posibles y el problema persiste. Estoy usando Sass y flexbox. Dejo una imagen para que se vea mejor el problema. Los archivos html y css los estoy haciendo por separado uno para la cabecera, otro para el menu, otro para el "slider (aunque no este hecho)" y eso es todo lo que maquete por el momento.

Gracias [image: Problema ancho]

```css
$menu-font: "Oswald", sans-serif;
$primary-font: "Arimo", sans-serif;
$primary-color: #364f6b;
$seconday-color: #fc5185;
$third-color: #f0f0f0;

// Funciones se usan con @include
@mixin input-styles() {
}

@mixin btn-styles($color) {
}

@mixin btn($color) {
  @include border-radius(10px);
  background-color: $color;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: $menu-font;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@mixin border($grosor, $tipo, $color-borde) {
  border: $grosor $tipo $color-borde;
}

@mixin border-radius($radius) {
  border-radius: $radius;
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
  -moz-border-radius: $radius;
}

@mixin outstyles-btn() {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  color: inherit;
}

// Herencia de estilos se usa con @extend

html {
  min-width: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: $primary-font;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
// Barra superior

#barra-superior {
  width: auto;
  background-color: $primary-color;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  a {
    color: white;
  }
}

#datos-contacto {
  margin-top: 25px;

  .icons-cont {
    margin: 10px;
  }
}

#icons {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.caja-hijo-barra-superior {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#caja-nav {
  width: auto;
  background-color: $third-color;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 5vh;
  font-family: $menu-font;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(93, 93, 90, 0.3);

  ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;

    li {
      margin-top: 10px;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
  }
}
#slider {
  background-image: url("../img/fondo2.jpg");
  background-position: 30%;
  width: 128.068303094984vh;
  height: 64.034151547492vh;
  margin: 0px auto;

  #slider-cont {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: 50px;
    @include border-radius(25px);

    input {
      @include outstyles-btn();
      @include btn(black);
      @include border(1px, solid, black);
    }

    h1 {
      font-family: $menu-font;
    }
  }
}

#sub-banner {
  width: 128.068303094984vh;
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-top: 20px;

  a {
    height: 80px;
  }

  .banner:hover {
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <meta name="description" content="Buenos Vapores cigarrillos electronicos">
    <meta name="keywords" content="vape, vapeo, vapor, cigarrillos electronicos, vapeadores, mod, atomizador, claromizador, rta, rda, e-liquids, liquidos vapeo">
    <meta name="author" content="Facundo Fernandez">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7d2bacf2e3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url ?>assets/scss/estilos.css">
    <title>Buenos Vapores cigarrillos electronicos</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Cabecera-->
    <header>
        <div id="barra-superior">
            <div id="datos-contacto" class="caja-hijo-barra-superior">
                <div><i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg icons-cont"></i><span class="datos-contacto">+34 674 144 460</span></div>
                <div><i class="far fa-envelope fa-lg icons-cont"></i><span class="datos-contacto">buenosvapores@gmail.com</span></div>
            </div>

            <div id="caja-logo" class="caja-hijo-barra-superior">
                <a href="<?= base_url ?>" id="logo"><img src="<?= base_url ?>assets/img/logo.png"></a>
            </div>

            <div id="icons" class="caja-hijo-barra-superior">
                <a href="index.php"><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg icons-cont"></i></a>
                <a href="<?= base_url ?>carrito/index" class="icono"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg icons-cont"></i></a>
                <a href="index.php"><i class="far fa-user fa-lg icons-cont"></i></a>
                <a href="<?= base_url ?>views/users/registro.php">Registro</a>
                <a href="<?= base_url ?>views/users/registro.php">Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </header>
        <div id="productos-destacados">
        <h1>Algunos de nuestros productos</h1>

        <?php while ($prod = $productos->fetch_object()) : ?>
            <div class="product">
                <a href="<?= base_url ?>producto/ver&id=<?= $prod->id ?>">
                    <?php if ($prod->img != null) : ?>
                        <img src="<?= base_url ?>uploads/img<?= $prod->img ?>" class="foto_edit">
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <img src="<?= base_url ?>assets/img/productos/generic.jpg" class="foto_edit">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <h2><?= $prod->nombre ?></h2>
                </a>
                <p><?= $prod->precio ?>€</p>
                <a href="<?= base_url ?>producto/ver&id=<?= $prod->id ?>" class="btn btn-compra">Comprar</a>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <footer id="footer">
    <p>Diseñado y desarrollado por Facundo Fernandez</p>
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: La imagen ayuda para entender lo que te está sucediendo, pero seguimos necesitando el **HTML** y el **CSS** con el que podamos reproducir el error. Me temo que sin eso será complicado ayudarte.

Comment: Ahi lo agregue, la verdad que no llego a ver el error.